# How can I add/change the Settings.Global.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE

Tags: android

I am trying to set the `Settings.Global.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE` value in Android by using

```
Settings.Global.putInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),key,value);
```

However, what ever value I set , I was not getting the value when do following `adb` command.

`adb shell settings get global package_verifier_enable`

Thanks InAdvance

Comment: I'm successfully able to write the Settings.Global.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE through my system service. However the value is not persisted after reboot the device. Where should i making the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the official [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) is described that

> Applications can read these **but are not allowed to write**; like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values.

This means that unless your app is running as system you're not allowed to write to those settings.

If you have the right signing certificate for the android operating system that you're using, you can sign your app to run with system privileges. As long as you're just running as a "normal" app there is no way to modify these settings.

You can however (which is bad practice) use **su** to set this setting via

`su -c 'settings set global package_verifier_enable 0'`

Comment: Now Im trying in system app,But still value is not reflecting .with same piece of code Settings.Global.putInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),key,value);

Comment: Thank you Louven, Its working  from System service . I am successfully write the value and same value is reflecting in adb shell command

Comment: on android 8 seems:  `settings put global xxx yyy`